# Unable to get the position in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a dynamic survey app, using a `RecyclerView`. I have no problem on initializing the primary questions. The issue is when I try to insert a row in the `recyclerView`.It is not placed where it is expected to be.  I wanted the row to be inserted next to the current row. I tried several methods like `getAdapterPosition`, `getLayoutPosition` for `viewholder` but I cant get the selected correct position of the view. Furthermore, the `RecyclerView` does stores the old location of a `view` when something is inserted. Could someone help me to figure this out or is there any easier approach. Furthermore, Thank you guys, I'm a newbie programmer.. Here is a snippet of my `Adapter` where I create and initialize `dynamic views`.

Comment: please explain in brief. what you want exactly ? :)

Comment: call `setOnClickListener` inside `SurveyForm_*` constructor

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, alright.. I have recyclerview that pulls multiple view layout. 

1. Now, for example in a row with a radio button, if that is clicked. I wanted to insert another row after that current view. 
2. The first attempt of inserting the row is working fine. 
3. Next attempt of doing the same in number 1. The row is inserted to a wrong location. it seems that view layout retains the old position initial rows.

Comment: if you are inserting the view, update the row value in the main list also
and set `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Hi pskink, what will I put on on the setOnclickListner? BTW i tried to follow this guide upon creating this app

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: Thank you for the reply Benjith, yes i tried that. But another problem occurs if I used the notifyDataSetChanged(). As you can see from the code, I am creating child views with dynamic radio buttons. When I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged, it repopulates the buttons in the row, making it twice, 3x etc.

Comment: just call `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)` inside custom `ViewHolder` constructor

Comment: @pskink okay.. so for each viewholder layout, I'll place a listener..is that right?  then how can I acquire the position in the recycler view?

Comment: not for each: do it in your base `ViewHolder` class - and you will know the position if you read `ViewHolder` javadocs

Comment: @pskink, thank you for your help... I actually calling the wrong adapterPosition for the view. I'm glad that I figured it out through your help... btw, how can I mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What i always do and works fine is to use `tag`.
for example you have a radio button and you have an item ( Question , single choice etc... ) .
before you assign a clicklistener to your view just put that item as tag

```
MYVIEW.setTag(MyItem);
```

so in your clicklistener just do this :

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ITEM item = (ITEM)v.getTag();
        int alwaysTruePosition = items.indexOf(item);
        ...

       }
}
```

Important note is that you should define `equal` method in your ITEM class and there should be a unique identifier which helps you to define are two objects the same or not. (for example a unique id or unique name )